# If-else-statement returns undefined in palindrome function

Tags: javascript, recursion, undefined

In my **palindrome** function an `if-else-statement` returns undefined. Basically, I am trying to find the biggest palindromic number with three digits. For example with two digits: `99 * 91 = 9009`.

```
var palindromic = function(n) {
    var save,
        result,
        counter = 900;

    var checker = function(string) {
        s = string.toString();

        if(!(s)) {
            return true;
        } else if(s[0] !== s[s.length - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
        checker(s.slice(1, -1));
    }

    var recursive = function() {
        result = counter * n;
        if(counter === n) {
            return;
        } else if(checker(result)) { // this line of code here, undefined.
            save = result;
        }
        counter++;
        recursive();
    }

    recursive();
    return save;
};
```

What is wrong? Any help is welcome!

Comment: I am a beginner, any advice on improving the code is very welcome!!!

Comment: you may want to show the output that you're getting (or error that's occuring)

Comment: When I checked the console, whenever checker() returns true it is undefined. However, every number that is not a palindrome returns false as expected!

Comment: What should be the *input* and the *output*? What should be *n* in your function. Can you clarify your question and provide an **example** that it gets clearer what you want to achieve.

Comment: For example, input: 99, output: 9009. When counter reaches 99, it stops. As counter increments, counter multiplies 99. Checker() see first and last number matches, recurses with '00'. Checker sees that 00 matches, it slices, and recurses with empty string. If there it is a empty string, it must be palindrome, returns true. Goes back recursive() save will save the result of 91*99, which is 9009. In the end, palindromic() returns save, or the last palindromic number.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the code

1. `checker()` should have `return checker(s.slice(1,-1));` as last line.
2. In `recursive()` when `checker(result)` is true recursive() should return.

Here's corrected code.

```
var palindromic = function (n) {
    var save,
        result, 
        counter = 900;

    var checker = function (s) {
        //s = string.toString();

        if ( !(s) ) {
            return true;
        } else if ( s[0] !== s[s.length-1] ) {
            return false;
        }
        return checker(s.slice(1,-1));
    }     

    var recursive = function () {
        result = counter * n;
        if ( counter === n ) {
            return;
        } else if ( checker(result + "") ) { // this line of code here, undefined.
            save = result;
            return;
        }
        counter++;
        recursive();
    } 

    recursive();
    return save;
};
```

**Output:**

```
palindromic(2)
2002
palindromic(3)
2772
palindromic(5)
5005
palindromic(6)
6006
palindromic(9)
8118
palindromic(23423)
188484881
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A little spoiler and improving

You can do it without a recursion.

1. Usage of a **reverse** **function** to reverse a string.
2. Usage of two for loops, starting from the **highest** number.

```js
function strReverse(str) {
    var reverse = "";
    for(var i = (str.length - 1); i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        reverse += str[i];
    }
    return reverse;
}

function palindromic(n) {
    var highestPalindrom = 0;
    // Start with the highest number! 
    for(var i = n; i > 1; i -= 1) {
        // Start also with the highest number!
        for(var j = n; j > 1; j -= 1) {
            // Get product
            var product = i * j;
            // Compare the string in reverse with the string itself
            // If it is true, then it is a palindrom!
            if(strReverse(product.toString()) === product.toString()) {
                highestPalindrom = product;
                // Break inner loop
                break;
            }
        }
        // Break outer loop
        break;
    }
    return highestPalindrom;
}

var hP = palindromic(99);
console.log(hP);
```